# Does Spotipy break after a certain number of requests? Hitting API too much?

Tags: spotify, spotipy

I had a script that ran for about ~1hr.

df is a data frame created by rows I queried from my own Postgres database.
I'm iterating over that to get the artist_name value and make the API call.

There are ~47k records in that table.

After an hour or so, the script stopped giving me any responses. There are no errors.

The line that breaks is `results = artist_albums(...)`

Putting a breakpoint() before works but once that line runs, It stops. No status errors, 429, etc...

Did I hit the Spotipy API too much?

````
for idx, val in enumerate(df['artist_name']):

    #get albums for each artist  
    results = artist_albums('spotify:artist:'+df['artist_name'], album_type='album')
    albums = results['items']
    while results['next']:
        results = spotify.next(results)
        albums.extend(results['items'])

    sleep(0.5)

    for album in albums:
        print(album['name'])
        try:
            q = (album['name'],
            album['id'],
            album['uri'],
            album['release_date'],
            album['release_date_precision'],
            album['total_tracks'],
            album['artists'][0]['id'],
            album['type'],
            album['external_urls']['spotify']
            )
            )
            cur.execute("""insert into schema.table values (
            %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,
            %s, %s, %s, %s)""", q)
            conn.commit()
    ```
````

Comment: The quick fix was to generate new keys, but is there a way to distribute the querying to not hit the endpoint too frequently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably hit Spotiy API's [rate limits](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/guides/rate-limits/), which works in a 30-seconds rolling window.

> If your app makes a lot of Web API requests in a short period of time
> then it may receive a 429 error response from Spotify. This indicates
> that your app has reached our Web API rate limit. The Web API has rate
> limits in order to keep our API reliable and to help third-party
> developers use the API in a responsible way.

> Spotify’s API rate limit is calculated based on the number of calls that your app makes to Spotify in a rolling 30 second window.

A way to avoid this would be to introduce some waiting time between API calls, for example using [time.sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep), i.e.:

```py
import time
time.sleep(10) # sleeps for 10 seconds
```